# How do you push your commits to an SVN repositor?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

Once you have checked out a SVN repository with git-svn, and you do some work, how do you push your commits to the SVN repository?

Comment: Most of these types of "how to" questions have answers on google and other online sources; like here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion

Answer (score 3):

You can push them back to your SVN repo with [**`git svn dcommit`**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn)

> Commit each diff from a specified head directly to the SVN repository, and then rebase or reset (depending on whether or not there is a diff between SVN and head).
>   This will create a revision in SVN for each commit in git.

It is also possible to make [just one SVN revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158514/is-it-possible-to-make-git-svn-dcommit-result-in-a-single-svn-commit) when pushing back.

Note:

> It is recommended that you run git svn fetch and rebase (not pull or merge) your commits against the latest changes in the SVN repository.

That will avoid merge conflict resolution *locally* (in your git repo) before sending back the result in the SVN repo.

If the `dcommit` operation fails in the middle of transmitting a large number of commit, this [blog post](http://blogs.gnome.org/diegoe/2009/03/18/saving-your-neck-when-git-svn-dcommit-fails/) can show you how to pick up where you left off.

Answer (score 0):

You can push the commits you have done with git svn dcommit

git-svn is a way to use a subversion repository with the git toolset.